# Google calendar crashing, can't delete events

Tags: google-apps-script

I made a disastrous mistake. I used Microsoft Flow to add my google calendar invites to outlook, and then my outlook calendars to google. Obviously this created a circular funhouse of calendar invites and now I have thousands of calendar events that is crashing my calendar from opening.

I'd like to mass delete all of these events. I created a Google script that deletes events with a specific subject line leveraging the the following:

```
function delete_events() {
  var fromDate = new Date(2019,8,16,15,0,0); 
  var toDate = new Date(2019,8,18,11,0,0);  
  var calendarName = 'my email address';
  var toRemove = 'Heather Unavailable';
  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName(calendarName)[0];
  var events = calendar.getEvents(fromDate, toDate,{search: toRemove});
  for(var i=0; i<events.length;i++) {
    var ev = events[i];//duplicate declaration
    if(ev.getTitle()==toRemove) {//check if the title matches
      var ev = events[i];//duplicate declaration
      Logger.log(ev.getTitle()); // show event name in log
      ev.deleteEvent();
    }
  }
}
```

However, I'm getting an error:

You have been creating or deleting too many calendars or calendar events in a short time. Please try again later. (line 18, file "Code")

Please help!

Comment: Take a look at this: https://support.google.com/a/answer/2905486?hl=en.  You may presently be in read only mode for a while.

Comment: hmm, I have a paid plan though? I don't think I hit 100k, gosh I hope not.

Comment: Well that basically about 1 per second so if you did several thousand in a a few minutes your way over the quota even though you didn't hit the 100000 mark.  So any way I try not to worry about it and come back in the morning and take a look.

Comment: You have two `var ev` declarations. I marked them with duplicate comments

Comment: You can also try using `Utilities.sleep()` between iterations, or just deleting a few hundred at a time and put the script on a timed trigger every hour.

Comment: I'm still hitting the max and the request is failing. @amolina, i'm not a developer, would you be able to add the correct line of code in the above script?  Thank you!

Comment: Hi @HeatherWatkins just wanted to check if the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function delete_events() {
  var fromDate = new Date(2019,8,16,15,0,0); 
  var toDate = new Date(2019,8,18,11,0,0);  
  var calendarName = 'my email address';
  var toRemove = 'Heather Unavailable';
  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName(calendarName)[0];
  var events = calendar.getEvents(fromDate, toDate,{search: toRemove});
  var ev;

  for(var i=0; i<events.length;i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < 200; j++){
      ev = events[i];
      if(ev.getTitle()==toRemove) {//check if the title matches
        Logger.log(ev.getTitle()); // show event name in log
        ev.deleteEvent();
      }
    }
    Utilities.sleep(5000);
  }
}
```

This will wait 5 seconds between deleting batches of 200 events, you can play around with the number of events to delete and the wait. Alternatively you can read into [Batch Requests](https://developers.google.com/calendar/batch) to better manage large numbers of requests, if you do, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48310991/11581830) provides an example with Drive API (You would need the [delete event method](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/delete) from the Calendar API)